# c# make a program minimize to task bar

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0

I am trying to make my application minimize to task bar/tray

Here is my code so far that I have pulled together from other SO posts and other people seem to have it working but my app minimizes to the tray but when I click it in the tray it doesn't reopen.

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            this.notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
    private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

just to explain again the problem is the application minimizes to the tray but when I click on the icon it doesn't restore the app to normal. Instead it does nothing.

Comment: That code should work.  Are you sure the code in notifyIcon1_DoubleClick() is being executed?

Comment: I forgot to add the events to the designer I added them and its working like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

what I didn't do was this

> Set the NotifyIcon's visible property to false in the property editor. Now go to the property editor of Form1, click on the little lightning symbol to access the events, and double click on the Resize event, and change the code to:

and I also didn't do this

> Finally we need the code to make the program show up again when the icon is double clicked. So double click on NotifyIcon1 in the designer,

I found this information here
[Dreamincode](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/116283-make-your-application-minimize-to-system-tray-in-c#/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used in the past but I fund a copy online at the link below

```
 if (FormWindowState.Minimized == this.WindowState)
 {
      notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
      notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500);
      this.Hide();    
 }
```

found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27599/Minimize-window-to-system-tray